# Can someone help me to solve my echo problem for my temperature converter PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, echo

So here is my code for temperature conversion in PHP

```
<html>
<head> 
      <title>Temp Conversion</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form name="tempConvert" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter value to convert</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="valueConvert" id="valueConvert" size="15"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Convert from:</td>
            <td><select name="convertFrom" id="convertFrom" size="1">
                       <option disabled> Select a measurement type</option>
                       <option value="celsiusF">Celsius</option>
                       <option value="fahrenheitF">Fahrenheit</option>
                       <option value="kelvinF">Kelvin</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>Convert to:</td>
            <td><select name="convertType" id="convertType" size="1">
                       <option disabled> Select a measurement type</option>
                       <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                       <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
                       <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnConvert" id="btnConvert" value="Convert"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>



    </form>

    <?php
        function tempConvert($valueConvert, $convertFrom, $convertType)
        {
            if($convertFrom== "celciusF")
            {
                if($convertType== "fahrenheit")
                {
                   $conversion = (((9/5)*$valueConvert) +(32));
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "celsius")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert);
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "kelvin")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert + 273);
                }
            
            }
            
            else if($convertFrom== "fahrenheitF")
            {
                if($convertType== "fahrenheit")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert);
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "celsius")
                {
                   $conversion = (($valueConvert - 32) * (5/9));
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "kelvin")
                {
                   $conversion = ((($valueConvert - 32) * (5/9)) + 273);
                }
            
            }
            
            else if($convertFrom== "kelvinF")
            {
                if($convertType== "fahrenheit")
                {
                   $conversion = (((9/5)*($valueConvert - 273)) +(32));
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "celsius")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert - 273);
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "kelvin")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert);
                }
            
            }
            
        
        }

        if (isset($_POST['btnConvert'])) 
        { 
            $valueConvert = $_POST['valueConvert'];
            $convertFrom = $_POST['convertFrom'];
            $convertType = $_POST['convertType'];
            $conversion = tempConvert($valueConvert, $convertFrom, $convertType);
            
            echo "The initial temperature was $valueConvert. The new temperature is $conversion $convertType.";
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this PHP code, then inserting the value, and pressing the convert button. It seems that the $conversion value does not shown in the echo at the last part of the code.
(for example it will only be shown like "The initial temperature was 32. The new temperature is celsius")

I wonder what caused the problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: `tempConvert` doesn't return the value to be printed.

Comment: You forgot to `return` anything from your function

Comment: You need `return $conversion;` at the end of the function.

Comment: Hmm, though even after adding the return $conversion; before the end bracket in function tempConvert. It nows add an error (Warning: Undefined variable $conversion in D:\Xammp\htdocs\temp.php on line 106)

Comment: and the $conversion value is still not shown at the echo

Comment: I also tried to add return on every $conversion when it is mentioned inside the function, but it is still does not solve my problem

Comment: Alright I finally get my problem, it seems that there is also a typo in my code, thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Nigel Ren, ADyson, and Barmar answer, it seems that I have 2 problem in my code, the first is the lack of return value, and the second is a typo when typing "celciusF" (it should be celsiusF, using s instead of c)

Here is the correct code

```
<html>
<head> 
      <title>Temp Conversion</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form name="tempConvert" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter value to convert</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="valueConvert" id="valueConvert" size="15"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Convert from:</td>
            <td><select name="convertFrom" id="convertFrom" size="1">
                       <option disabled> Select a measurement type</option>
                       <option value="celsiusF">Celsius</option>
                       <option value="fahrenheitF">Fahrenheit</option>
                       <option value="kelvinF">Kelvin</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>Convert to:</td>
            <td><select name="convertType" id="convertType" size="1">
                       <option disabled> Select a measurement type</option>
                       <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                       <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
                       <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnConvert" id="btnConvert" value="Convert"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>



    </form>

    <?php
        function tempConvert($valueConvert, $convertFrom, $convertType)
        {
            if($convertFrom== "celsiusF")
            {
                if($convertType== "fahrenheit")
                {
                   $conversion = (((9/5)*$valueConvert) +(32));
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "celsius")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert);
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "kelvin")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert + 273);
                }
            
            }
            
            else if($convertFrom== "fahrenheitF")
            {
                if($convertType== "fahrenheit")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert);
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "celsius")
                {
                   $conversion = (($valueConvert - 32) * (5/9));
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "kelvin")
                {
                   $conversion = ((($valueConvert - 32) * (5/9)) + 273);
                }
            
            }
            
            else if($convertFrom== "kelvinF")
            {
                if($convertType== "fahrenheit")
                {
                   $conversion = (((9/5)*($valueConvert - 273)) +(32));
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "celsius")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert - 273);
                }
                
                else if ($convertType== "kelvin")
                {
                   $conversion = ($valueConvert);
                }
            
            }
            
        return $conversion;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['btnConvert'])) 
        { 
            $valueConvert = $_POST['valueConvert'];
            $convertFrom = $_POST['convertFrom'];
            $convertType = $_POST['convertType'];
            $conversion = tempConvert($valueConvert, $convertFrom, $convertType);
            
            echo "The initial temperature was $valueConvert. The new temperature is $conversion $convertType.";
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo questions can be simply deleted,  the answer is unlikely to be of use to anyone else in future.  Glad you solved it though